# Anonymous Access to Report Server SQL 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I implement Anonymous Access for Reporting Service with SQL 2012?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437963/anonymous-authentication-in-ssrs-2016/)

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you want to allow anonymous access to your report server in (I assume) a production environment.

If by 'anonymous access' you simply mean that want all users in your domain to be able to access the reports you publish to the report server (I'd think about this also - obviously I don't know where you work or what reports you are producing, but do you really want very junior staff seeing profit/loss accounts for example?) I suggest you start by reading the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522824(v=sql.110).aspx).