# anonymous authentication in SSRS 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am in a problem is that I am accessing my report server from a website, but as I have embedded the report on the website I do not want to show the authentication prompt, but I know that the anonymous authentication in SSRS 2016, I would like know how I can solve this.

I mean window authentication, when you try to remotely access the Report Server, it shows you the window prompt, when I have that report embedded in my website, it will do the same to ask me for the window password, and I will I want to connect anonymously, but sql server 2016 does not allow anonymous authentication[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReHAU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReHAU.png)

Comment: did you check the security against the report?

Comment: All you have to do is save the credentials in the data source properties on the report server.

Comment: Yes, but I also want that if someone accesses from a remote ip The ReportServer does not show the prompt

Comment: I've setup a database user to run my reports with. Then all you have to do is manage the report folder permissions.

Answer (score 1):

For whoever else is fashionably late: you can implement a custom authentication for anonymous access, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/authentication-with-the-report-server):

> The report server will not accept unauthenticated requests from an anonymous user, except for those deployments that include a custom authentication extension.

There is a good example by [James Wu](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/archive/blogs/jameswu/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008) for SSRS 2008, which I got working for 2017.  However, as he said:

> why would you want everyone on the internet to be able to view/update/overwrite your stuff on the report server?
>   DO NOT USE ANONYMOUS AUTH!
>   NEVER USE IT IN PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT!

Emphasize: all (anonymous) users can then also **update the settings**.  (You may be able to prevent this by not providing binding (or only a machine-binding) for `/Reports`.  I am not an expert on this.)

If you still want to use it, just make sure that you adapt *all* the config-settings correctly, and update `IAuthenticationExtension` to `IAuthenticationExtension2` with an extra method:

```
    public void GetUserInfo(IRSRequestContext requestContext, out IIdentity userIdentity, out IntPtr userId)
    {
        userIdentity = new GenericIdentity("Dummy user");
        userId = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

For compilation I also had to include `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\bin\Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll` (there does not seem to be an official Nuget).